# I Can't Access Google Playstore Nor Gmail On My Huawei Y220

Tags: huawei, google-play-services

My Huawei Running On Android v2.3.6 can't access gmail and google playstore anymore. I deleted the pre installed Emails but everything was working fine until when I once switched the phone off and when I switches it on, anytime I open the gmail app, it shows a blank white page which doesnt last for a second. when I open playstore, they tell me to add a gmail account but when I try adding, I am sent back to the home screen. it is rooted. ia there anything I can do to make it function like before?

Comment: It might help to [edit] your question and include exactly what and how you deleted. Looks very much like you deleted too much while using your "root powers".

Comment: I deleted the maps and emails but <b>NOT</b> Gmail. I did it with titanium backup

Comment: Which *files* exactly did you delete? Hint: Next time, better try *freezing* apps first to check for potential side-effects before deleting files. And *when* deleting files, keep a backup somewhere so you'd be able to put them back if needed :)

Comment: All right, thanks. I Reinstalled Google Play Services And It Came Back To Normal. Thanks For Yo Comments, I Really Appreciate It ;)

Comment: Glad you've solved it! May I ask you to make that an answer, including some more details, and then accept it? That would then help others in similar situations to identify this problem here has a solution. Thanks a lot!